# Identify group of data in a timeseries with sparse nan in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have a time series with group of data separated by long gaps (filled with nans as I'm working with a regularly spaced time series). I would like to identify these groups and separate them, however these data are not very regular, in particular:

- There is roughly one group of data per hour but they are not strictly confined within the same hour
- The time resolution is 5 seconds (this is fixed)
- The number of data in each group is not fixed but they are roughly 10 minutes long
- There are missing data in each group (10%-20% roughly)
- The start time of each data group can vary of several minutes (in some cases is a drift in others is a step change)

I can achieve this result by looping over the dataframe elements and look for consecutive missing data above a certain threshold (5 or 10 minutes for example). However this is a slow and ugly solution.

I checked the itertools and more-itertools libraries but I didn't find any solution that could serve my scope. The more_itertools.consecutive_groups function does something similar but I don't know how to use it to handle the missing data in each group.

I'm looking more for a general idea/implementation scheme but if you want to play with some data you can generate a random time series with the code below. However, this is not perfectly representative as the starting time and duration of each group is fixed.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

idx= pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01 00:00:00', end='2019-01-01 23:00:00',freq='5s')
df=pd.DataFrame(index=idx)
df['data']=np.nan
df[(df.index.minute>5)&(df.index.minute<15)]=1

idxlist=df[(df.index.minute>5)&(df.index.minute<15)].index
randidx=np.random.choice(idxlist,500)
df.loc[pd.DatetimeIndex(randidx)]=np.nan
```

**Edit:**

I don't have a strict definition for a "group" but if you plot the data from the example above it should be obvious. Data comes in bunches and are separated by long intervals of nan, each of these bunches is a group. Here an image showing an example from my real data.

[image]

The expected result should be a list whose elements are the indexes corresponding to each group, or alternatively starting time and end time of each group or something similar. Again, I'm more interested in ideas or suggestions on how can I achieve this, I can take care of the implementation myself.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "separate them?" could you add the expected result? Possibly with 20 or 30 rows, not 16000.

Comment: @Valentino I edit my question, I hope is more clear now.

Comment: If you don't need to keep the small gaps inside the groups, you could just use [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to get all the non `NaN` rows.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but if I remove the NaN then I don't think I would be able to identify the groups anymore.

Comment: No, it should be easier by comparing the diff of dates. Let me write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could drop all the `NaN` values and then compare the difference between consecutive rows using [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html). You select a threshold big enough to be sure that is a new group and not just few missing values (in the following example I choose a threshold of 50 minutes) and if the difference is bigger than the threshold, that is the starting of a new group. Previous row is the end of the previous group.

For example:

```
#replicating your data
idx= pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01 00:00:00', end='2019-01-01 23:00:00',freq='5s')
df=pd.DataFrame(index=idx)
df['data']=np.nan
df[(df.index.minute>5)&(df.index.minute<15)]=1

idxlist=df[(df.index.minute>5)&(df.index.minute<15)].index
randidx=np.random.choice(idxlist,500)
df.loc[pd.DatetimeIndex(randidx)]=np.nan

#searching for the groups
ddf = df.dropna().reset_index()
threshold = pd.Timedelta(50, 'm')
starting = ddf['index'].loc[ddf['index'].diff() > threshold]
```

`starting` is:

```
82     2019-01-01 01:06:05
165    2019-01-01 02:06:00
256    2019-01-01 03:06:05
344    2019-01-01 04:06:00
434    2019-01-01 05:06:00
527    2019-01-01 06:06:00
607    2019-01-01 07:06:00
699    2019-01-01 08:06:00
784    2019-01-01 09:06:00
869    2019-01-01 10:06:00
961    2019-01-01 11:06:00
1049   2019-01-01 12:06:00
1135   2019-01-01 13:06:00
1225   2019-01-01 14:06:00
1321   2019-01-01 15:06:00
1409   2019-01-01 16:06:00
1498   2019-01-01 17:06:00
1590   2019-01-01 18:06:00
1686   2019-01-01 19:06:00
1774   2019-01-01 20:06:00
1865   2019-01-01 21:06:05
1946   2019-01-01 22:06:05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Each row reports the times of the beginning of a new group. Actually, you are missing the first row of `ddf`, which also is the starting of a group.

To go further, you could calculate the ending times. Simply take the previous row in `ddf` of each row selected in `starting`. Remember to add the last row of `ddf`. By doing like this, you can have starting and ending times, and you can put them together in a dataframe.

```
ending = ddf['index'].loc[starting.index-1]

#adding first row of ddf to starting, and last row of ddf to ending
starting = pd.Series(ddf['index'].iloc[0]).append(starting)
ending = ending.append(pd.Series(ddf['index'].iloc[-1]))

#make a dataframe, each row contains starting and ending times of a group
groups = pd.DataFrame({'start':starting.reset_index(drop=True), 'end':ending.reset_index(drop=True)})

#this is groups
                 start                 end
0  2019-01-01 00:06:10 2019-01-01 00:14:55
1  2019-01-01 01:06:05 2019-01-01 01:14:50
2  2019-01-01 02:06:00 2019-01-01 02:14:55
3  2019-01-01 03:06:05 2019-01-01 03:14:55
4  2019-01-01 04:06:00 2019-01-01 04:14:55
5  2019-01-01 05:06:00 2019-01-01 05:14:50
6  2019-01-01 06:06:00 2019-01-01 06:14:45
7  2019-01-01 07:06:00 2019-01-01 07:14:50
8  2019-01-01 08:06:00 2019-01-01 08:14:55
9  2019-01-01 09:06:00 2019-01-01 09:14:55
10 2019-01-01 10:06:00 2019-01-01 10:14:55
11 2019-01-01 11:06:00 2019-01-01 11:14:55
12 2019-01-01 12:06:00 2019-01-01 12:14:55
13 2019-01-01 13:06:00 2019-01-01 13:14:55
14 2019-01-01 14:06:00 2019-01-01 14:14:55
15 2019-01-01 15:06:00 2019-01-01 15:14:55
16 2019-01-01 16:06:00 2019-01-01 16:14:55
17 2019-01-01 17:06:00 2019-01-01 17:14:55
18 2019-01-01 18:06:00 2019-01-01 18:14:55
19 2019-01-01 19:06:00 2019-01-01 19:14:55
20 2019-01-01 20:06:00 2019-01-01 20:14:55
21 2019-01-01 21:06:05 2019-01-01 21:14:55
22 2019-01-01 22:06:05 2019-01-01 22:14:55
```

Comment: I tested your solution, it works perfectly also with the real dataset. Thanks a lot!